# Из-за границы или из заграницы

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать: "приехал из-за границы" или "приехал из заграницы"?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно "приехал из-за границы". Второй вариант - "приехал из заграницы" - разговорный.

Answer (score 2):

Если заграница понимается как существительное "заграница нам поможет"), то из неё можно приехать. Нормативность такого употребления не очевидна, но как разговорный вариант, думаю, все же возможно.

А вот можно ли приехать приехать "из-за границы" (как из-за леса, угла, шкафа) - это вопрос спорный. Предлог из-за в таком контексте выражает скорее причину, а не место (источник, отправную точку) - см. [[@Ивантис](/users/4238/%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81)](/users/4238/%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81).

Comment: А почему нет-то? Как раз "из-за границы" и приезжают в нормативном понимании..

Answer (score 1):

В России отключат Интернет из-за границы, вот что пишет помошник президента рф в своем блоге: [В России отключат Интернет](http://www.helpset.ru/%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82/) Наверное поэтому пора валить жить в Европу, за границу

Comment: Хотел минуснуть, потом шутка юмора дошла)))